# Floating left and right: left div is below right div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I can't figure out what to do in this situation.  When i have two divs floating right (with clear: right), followed by a div that is floated left, I want the left-floated div to be up at the top (in line with the first of the right-floated divs), but instead it's in line with the 2nd div.  Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jeremymoritz/78fk9Lgz/

```
<div class="red right"></div>
<div class="blue right"></div>
<p>Notice how the green floated-left divs are below the red div.  Why is that?</p>
<ul>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>1st List Item</li>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>2nd List Item</li>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>3rd List Item</li>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>4th List Item</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why is that? Because that's what clearing floats will do. You'd have to re-order your HTML elements, or use CSS or JavaScript to change the position of the green div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a little more careful about how often you are using "clear" when relating to "float" elements. Try putting the color divs inside of wrapper:

```
<div class="right">
  <div class="red">
  <div class="blue">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position):

> 5. The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document.

In this case, your right floats precede your left float in the source, so your left float is not allowed to be positioned higher than the second right float (the one that's closer to it in the source). Because the second element clears the first, any succeeding floats are indirectly affected. This is regardless of the clearance direction because clearance does not change the behavior of succeeding floats.

However, if you don't float your left element at all, then it is ignored by the right floats and allowed to rise as high as possible, as part of normal flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="red right"></div>
<div class="green left"></div>
<div class="blue right"></div>
```

The green div floats left on the next line because it comes after the blue div in the markup.

Comment: This is merely an example.  In my actual code, i don't have the luxury of changing this.  The html needs to be in the order it is now.

Comment: Well, you could do this: .green{margin-top: -100px;} But then you have to deal with the text, at least in the example.  Another option is to create divs that act like columns and float the columns left and right and fill them with the colored divs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not saying what can you do and what aren't you able to change. It looks like you can only change CSS, but at the same time you don't say why do you have those properties, because the obvious answer is to have your CSS like:

```
.right {float: right; }
.left {float: left; }
```

Basically, make your mind and define if you want to clear floats or not. If you want to clear floats anyways, then you could use some absolute positioning. Ugly but could work.

Then again, the answer to your question is to **clear the floats**, the behavior you're observing is exactly what you will expect from what you have done.

Just in case, take a read to [CLEAR PROPERTY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) page so you understand how it works. The pertinent part for your case:

> When applied to non-floating blocks, it moves the border edge of the
>   element down until it is below the margin edge of all relevant floats.
>   This movement (when it happens) causes margin collapsing not to occur.
>
> When applied to floating elements, it moves the margin edge of the
>   element below the margin edge of all relevant floats. This affects the
>   position of later floats, since later floats cannot be positioned
>   higher than earlier ones.
>
> The floats that are relevant to be cleared are the earlier floats
>   within the same block formatting context.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class **left** from your third div and it should work

`class="green"`

http://jsfiddle.net/Tudor1201/78fk9Lgz/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use clear:both after blue color.

```
    <div class="red right"></div>
    <div class="blue right"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="green left"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want the green div to be below the red and blue.  i wanted it to appear up at the top.  it appears i would need to either reorder the elements (can't do that in my specific case) or use javascript

Comment: is it possible for you to draw an image of what exactly yor look for? so it gives a better idea to do for me.

Comment: <div class="right"><div class="red right">
</div>
<div class="blue right">
    </div></div>

<ul>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>1st List Item</li>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>2nd List Item</li>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>3rd List Item</li>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>4th List Item</li>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>5th List Item</li>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>6th List Item</li>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>7th List Item</li>
    <li><div class="green left"></div>8th List Item</li>
</ul>

Comment: Sure.  Here's the actual page where I have this issue: http://www.rhythmcity.org/licensing

Answer (score -1):

You can use `float:top`. Try this **CSS**:

```
div {
width: 80px;
height: 100px;
}
.red {background: red;}
.blue {background: blue;}
.green {background: green;}
.purple {background: purple;}
.right {float: right; clear: right;}
.left {float: top;clear: left;}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78fk9Lgz/8/)**

Comment: There is no float:top.  The reason this appears to work in your fiddle is because you're essentially removing the float value by assigning it to something that doesn't exist